# closing Lightbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

I'm using lightbox on my html5 website, the website has lightbox to show the page section.

in my portfolio section (it's a lightbox already opened) I have my picture with small preview, in the preview are two clickable links, the first will open another lightbox with the big picture and the second link needs to close the portfolio lightbox and open the lightbox for the portfolio item.

I tried calling a JavaScript function from the href from the link but didn't worked.

This is the function I used to close to try to close the lightbox, found it googling it, but it's not working.

```
function processAction(hideElemId, navElemId)
{
    var elemToHide = null;
    alert("closing lightbox function");
    
    try
    {
        elemToHide = document.getElementById(hideElemId);
        elemToHide.setAttribute("style", "display:none"); 

        window.location.hash = navElemId;

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("processAction Error:  " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

sorry for the late response.
i'm very new to html5, i'm posting the section where i'm thinking the lightbox is opening, sorry if this is not the code you asked.

```
<div class="lightbox-wrapper" id="portfolio" name="portfolio" data-simplebar>
<div class="container">
  <div class="lightbox-close">
    <div class="close-btn" data-modal-close="" id="btn_light"><span class="btn-line"></span></div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="lightbox-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="section-heading page-heading">
              <p class="section-description">Showcasing my works</p>
              <h2 class="section-title">Portfolio</h2>
              <div class="animated-bar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: paste the code that opens the ligthbox and by looking at how it is opened we can try to close it. Even better if you make a codepen or jsfiddle. People will try to poke around a lot more if available.

Answer (score 0):

$(".lightbox").hide();

will hide the lightbox  or you can use your proper class name.